# In PowerBI Line graph how to plot a constant value against time

Tags: powerbi

In PowerBI, if my data(where v is value and T is timestamp) looks as follows

```
V1  T1
V6  T6
V8  T8
```

the Value of V1 is constant for time T2-T5...Only the change in data are recorded.
When I use a Line Graph to plot the V against T, the value of V is averaged from T2-T5, but I want it to stay the same as V1. How could I plot this graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK this isn't supported easily in PBI. In other domains it's commonly called a Step Chart.

I would go back to the Queries layer and construct a "Next T" query of all the Values (bar the last) with an "Next T" value against each.  For your example that would be:

```
V1 T5
V6 T7
```

Then I would use the Append command to add the "Next T" query data together with your base table, and feed that into the Line Chart.

To get this looking nice, make the Next T values as close as possible to their source T values, e.g. 1 second before.